# C: Count positive/negative numbers and 0's in array

Tags: c, count, nul

I'm trying to write a program in C to count the number of positive and negative numbers in an array as well as the number of zeroes.

I have written the following code:

```
int A[15], pos, neg, nul, i;

[...]

pos = 0;
neg = 0;
nul = 0;

for (i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
    if (A[i] > 0) {
        pos++;
    }
    if (A[i] < 0) {
        neg++;
    }
    if (A[i] == 0) {
        nul++;
    }
}
```

However, the counts are always wrong. Specifically, the count for `pos` and `nul` is always off by `1`. An array of 15 positive numbers and 1 zero gives `pos = 16` and `neg = 0`, while an array of 15 zeroes and 1 positive number gives `pos = 0` and `nul = 16`.

What's going on here and what to do about it?

Comment: How did you put 16 items into an array of 15? ("An array of 15 positive numbers and 1")

Comment: You are reading past your buffer.  You only have space for 15 elements, but you are continuing to the 16th element

Comment: The standard `for` loop used with an array of size `n` is `for (i=0; i<n; i++)`. In your code, `n` is 15, so the loop condition should be `i<15`

Answer (score 3):

**Problem:**

Your array size is **15** but you traverse it **16** times due to:

`for (i=0; i<=15; i++)`

Values of `i`: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}:

A total of 16 indices, where **A[15] is undefined behaviour.**

**Solution:**

Change that loop header to:

`for (i = 0; i < 15; i++)`

This will ensure that the loop runs 15 times with inbound array indices.

**Bonus:**

An array of `n` elements is generally traversed as:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    // process a[i] here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

the problem is here `for (i=0; i<=15; i++)` .You are passing boundaries of your array.

it should be `for (i=0; i<15; i++)`

Answer (score 1):

(i=0; i<=15; i++) will pass your arrays boundaries.

Your array size is 15 but since you are starting i from 0 your loop will run 16 times.

The solution is to write it as:

```
(i=0; i<15; i++)
```